# Cannot assign requested address (localhost:xxxx) - Docker + Linux Containers

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

We have a WPF application that will call a Web API called API-1 which is running in a docker container. I also have another API called API-2 which is also running in a docker but a different container.

Whenever the API-1 call happened from the application, the API-1 will do some logic and try to do a post request to API-2.

Now, my problem is, the post request to API-2 always returns **Cannot assign requested address (localhost:XXXX)**.

If I try without docker, it works fine.
Also, a separate request to each of the API works fine (using POSTMAN)

This problem occurs only if the API deployed in the docker. I was using docker-compose to create the containers. I have created a docker network bridge and allocated it to the respective APIs in the docker-compose.yml file.

Here is my docker-compose file as well as the docker file for both of the APIs.

***Docker-Compose.yml***

```
version: "3.7"

networks : 
  localdev:
    name: localdev
    external: true

services:
  api-01:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api-01/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: "api-01"
    ports:
       - "8082:80"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
    networks:
     - localdev

  api-02:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: api-02/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: "api-02"
    ports:
       - "8083:80"
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "Development"
    networks:
     - localdev
```

**DockerFile(API-1)**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["api-01/api-01.csproj", "api-01/"]
COPY ["CommonEntities/CommonEntities.csproj", "CommonEntities/"]
RUN dotnet restore "api-01/api-01.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/api-01"
RUN dotnet build "api-01.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "api-01.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api-01.dll"]
```

**DockerFile(API-2)**

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["api-02/api-02.csproj", "api-02/"]
COPY ["CommonEntities/CommonEntities.csproj", "CommonEntities/"]
RUN dotnet restore "api-02/api-02.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/api-02"
RUN dotnet build "api-02.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "api-02.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "api-02.dll"]
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here!
I have tried most of the solutions from the internet, but nothing works.

Comment: Where do you configure the location of the other service?  In Docker `localhost` almost always means "this container" and not another container, even if they're on the same physical system; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the host names available to connect between containers.

Comment: @DavidMaze - You're right. if I wanna call an API from an API in a different container, I need to use {DOCKER_IP} instead of localhost.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73020234/cannot-assign-requested-address-localhost4444

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you know why the error is "Cannot assign requested address" rather than "Connection refused" which I would expect to happen when trying to connect to a closed port?

Answer (score 12):

Using `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost` worked for me.

Source: https://hamy.xyz/labs/docker-dotnet-core-cannot-assign-requested-address

Answer (score 8):

It looks like I need to use {DOCKER_IP} instead of "localhost" if I want to have communication between two API in two different containers.

After I changed my post request to hit "http://{My_PC_IP_Address}:8082", the request was successful.

Thanks to David for redirecting me to the right documentation https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

Comment: Hint: You can get you PC IP address in Linux by `$ ifconfig` (in most cases go for the last one)