# Cannot assign requested address (localhost:4444)

Tags: c#, docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

I have problem with `Selenium` when I want to create a Image in Docker. In fact, I developed a `.Net Core Api` using `Selenium Chrome driver` and I need to create its `Docker container` to deploy it on a server. The interesting point is that it works properly locally, but I face an error when I create its Image and try to run it. 
It could but helpful to share my code.

It is a piece of code in which I instansiate `chrome driver` :

```cs
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
   options.AddArgument("headless");
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

**Dockerfile**

```
 FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest AS base
 WORKDIR /app

 # build and copy dotnet project
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
 COPY bin/Release/net5.0/publish/ app/
 WORKDIR /app
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Pand.dll"]
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:3.141.59-yttrium
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
    expose: 
      - 4444
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    container_name: chrome
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
        #Api  Service
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      #Use the DockerFile in that Directory
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment: 
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

And this is an error after I use `docker run -p 8080:80 pand/backend` command:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[6]
      Application startup exception
      OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session. The exception message was: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:4444)
       ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested address (localhost:4444)
       ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: If you're trying to connect to `localhost:4444` from inside your `pand/backend` container, that's trying to connect to itself, not another container or anything else on your host – `localhost` in Docker almost always means "the current container".

Comment: @DavidMaze I got it. But what changes do I make to solve the problem?

Comment: try your local IP address instead of localhost?